# Python - Increase read/modify/write speed?

Tags: python, performance

I have a geoJSON file, which contains a breakdown of a certain geographical area into ca. 7000 cells. I'd like to a) open this geoJSON b) modify some data (see code bellow) and c) write this modified geoJSON to the disk. Now, my problem is, that since there's a lot of cells, this takes almost a minute. Do you see any way to improve the speed of this function? Thank you!

```
def writeGeoJSON(param1, param2, inputdf):
    with open('ingeo.geojson') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for feature in data['features']: 
        currentfeature = inputdf[(inputdf['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId']) & (inputdf['param1']==param1) & (inputdf['param2']==param2)]
        if (len(currentfeature) > 0):
            feature['properties'].update({"style": {"opacity": currentfeature.Opacity.item()}})
        else:
            feature['properties'].update({"style": {"opacity": 0}})
    end = time.time()
    with open('outgeo.geojson', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Maybe calculate `inputdf[(inputdf['param1']==param1) & (inputdf['param2']==param2)]` outside of the loop.

Comment: First, [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/3005167) your function to find out if the bottleneck is in i/o or processing. Anything else is just fishing in the dark

Comment: @Alex Excellent! I've mentioned the same point in my answer. I noticed it the very minute the question was posted... I've taken 9 minutes to answer this question from my mobile!  xD

Comment: Did you try to store this `{"style": {"opacity": 0}}` in a constant ? Not sure if you will gain some perf with that, but if Python has to recreate each time this object, you can definetely be faster. Also, `feature['properties']` store this one into a variable could help. But again, I'm not sure. Python might access to the value faster than the variable creation, plus the access. Just make some tests.

Comment: @romain-aga I think you cannot store `{"style": {"opacity": 0}}` in a constant, since that's not a variable, but rather you're telling the program which fields of the JSON to update.

Comment: @romain-aga So the only constant there is the 0.

Comment: @lte__ `{ ... }` is a dictionary, it's an object. You can store it as a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **serial code optimization** possible in your code. You have the line:

```
currentfeature = inputdf[(inputdf['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId']) & (inputdf['param1']==param1) & (inputdf['param2']==param2
```

Notice that the last two checks can be put outside the `for` loop. It is a redundant check which takes up many CPU clock cycles for each iteration in the `for` loop!!!
You can modify the same as:

```
paramMatch=inputdf['param1']==param1 & inputdf['param2']==param2
for feature in data['features']: 
    currentfeature = inputdf[(inputdf['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId']) & paramMatch]
```

That must make your program run much faster!

That said, if you need better execution times(most probably not necessary), try using the `multiprocessing` module to parallelize the processing part of the code. You can try to split the work load in the `for` loop.

Try using `apply_async` or `map_async` to a block of iterations to speed things up!

Comment: Thanks, that cut running time by 60%! I'll try to make it run in parallel, too. :)

Comment: Awesome! Make sure you avoid the `Threading` module and use the  `multiprocessing` module if you're on Cpython (the default Python distribution). Otherwise, that can be an option too!

Comment: Yeah I've been working with `multiprocessing` before in a few uni assignments, so I'm familiar :)  As much as I know, `threading` doesn't do real parallel computing bc of the GIL. :)

Comment: Perfectly put, m8! All the best!  :D

Answer (score 1):

[In addition to @varun optimization, and including a @romain-aga suggestion.]

Add this at the beginning of the function:

```
zero_style = {"opacity": 0}
```

And change the conditional to become:

```
if (len(currentfeature) > 0):
    feature['properties']['style'] = {"opacity": currentfeature.Opacity.item()}
else:
    feature['properties']['style'] = zero_style
```

I have the impression that knowing more about `inputdf` type would lead to better optimization (maybe direct `if currentfeature:` is enough? maybe is better?)

---

Assuming CPython, I expect this to be better (better ask for forgiveness than for permission):

```
try:
    value = {"opacity": currentfeature.Opacity.item()}
except NotSureWhatExceptionMaybeAttributeError:
    value = zero_style
feature['properties']['style'] = value
```

Comment: +1 for that detailed observation. That's an interesting insight into the Python dictionary creation overhead in each iteration. I'll experiment and check if it makes a difference. I think it will make it a bit faster! :)